# NgOnInit not subscribing to observable in mockActivatedRoute in Jasmine tests

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a very simple component, as shown below. Please assume all relevant imports.

```
//my-component.component.ts
//imports, decorator, etc.
routingNumber: number;
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
    this.routingNumber = +params['id'];
      }
    );
}
```

I also have a test file, shown below. Once again, please assume all relevant import statements. I have a mockActivatedRoute that I use in place of the actual ActivatedRoute, with an associated observable. I was under the impression that calling fixture.onChanges() would run ngOnInit and set the routingNumber property value to the value being passed by the observable, but it always returns undefined when I run the test.

```
//my-component.component.spec.ts
//imports, describe, etc.

class mockActivatedRoute {
params = {
  subscribe() {
    return of({id: '1'});
  }
}

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      NoteService,
      {provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: mockActivatedRoute},
      {provide: DataStorageService, useValue: dataServiceStub}
    ],
    declarations: [MyComponent],
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
  }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});

it('should expect 1 as the route parameter', async(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.routingNumber).toEqual(1); 
});
```

Comment: `params = { subscribesubscribe`. That makes no sense. params is supposed to be an Observable. Not an object with a subscribesubscribe field. `params = of({id: '1'})`.

Comment: Right, sorry, that was a typographical error. It should be a simple subscribe() function that returns an observable. Although on second though, that wouldn't make much sense either. Regardless, your change does work.

Comment: Yes, it does. I tested it. Maybe you have **another** issue. BTW, you just accepted the answer telling you to use what I suggested you to use.

Comment: Yes, I responded to your answer hastily. I had mistyped something. Again. I changed my comment shortly after posting it when I realized this and found that your solution does, in fact, work correctly. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like -

```
params = of({id: '1'});

params.subscribe(  params => { console.log(params)
})
```